# WPF: Playing a segment of a Video File

Tags: c#, wpf, video, timer

I'm trying to play a .wmv using the MediaElement control one segment at a time.

I am using a timer to play/pause the video

But the Video playing keeps getting out of sync.

Any thoughts how to solve this issue ?

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer VideoTimer;
    private bool is_playing;

    private void PlaySegment(long duration_miliseconds,long offset_milisecond=-1)
    {
        if (is_playing) return;
        VideoTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(10000*duration_miliseconds);
        is_playing = true;
        if (offset_milisecond>=0)
            VideoControl.Position = new TimeSpan(10000*offset_milisecond);
        VideoControl.Play();
        VideoTimer.Start();
    }
    private void Timer_Stopped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        VideoControl.Pause();
        is_playing = false;
    }
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        VideoTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
        VideoTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(Timer_Stopped);
    }
}
```

And this is the relevant XAML Code:
`<MediaElement x:Name="VideoControl" LoadedBehavior="Manual" />`

Thank you !

Comment: You said that 'the Video playing keeps getting out of sync'... what does it get out of sync with?

Comment: Out of sync with the timer, for example the timer might measure 4300 milliseconds, but the MediaElement would plat 3500 milliseconds of the video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn on scrubbing...

```
VideoControl.ScrubbingEnabled = true;
```